# Autodesk Forge Viewer transparent background

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to use workaround described in the post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/transparent-background-viewer-long-last to set transparent background to the viewer.
And it is ok for desktop browsers. But if I try to open the same page (e.g. example page from the post) in Chrome/Safari browser on iPhone, the background isn't transparent.
Is there any solution to have a stable transparent background for the viewer?

Answer (score 0):

What's iOS version and what version of Chrome did you try? Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce the issue - I was able to get transparent background on my iOS 13.4.1 following the demo link in the blog article:

[image]

Comment: Bryan, try to open the same page on a desktop browser. I am sure, you'll see the difference

Comment: Actually, the latest version of Chrome and iOS. And the same for Safari (I didn't check other browsers or Android)